# Outlook Web Add-in using REST API slow to refresh in Outlook for Windows

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi, outlook-web-app

I am working on an Outlook add-in that uses the Outlook REST API extensively ... this works great in Outlook for the Web. It's very responsive and when I take an action against the REST API the UI updates almost instantaneously.

However, the same add-in when used in Outlook for Windows, has an extremely poor user experience. When I click a button to take an action, the action happens against the mailbox almost instantaneously (I can see it refresh in the web client open at the same time) but it can take 5-10 seconds before the UI on the full Outlook client updates.

Is there anything I can do to force the Outlook client to refresh the same way as Outlook web client or is this just a deficiency of the full Outlook?

Update:
I've created a side-by-side video of the full client and web client showing what I mean - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGEskXTt7S4

Answer (score 0):

By default the rich native Outlook client uses [Cached Exchange Mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-on-cached-exchange-mode-7885af08-9a60-4ec3-850a-e221c1ed0c1c) for a better overall user experience. This means that the rich native client relies on a local cache which gets updated periodically. The online/web client, however, is **always** online. Since you are making a REST call to the server, the web client will pick up the changes faster. After a few seconds, those changes will be pulled to the native client. There are also other differences between the rich client and the web client that could contribute in the delay you are experiencing. This delay will be observed for almost any REST call to make changes to the mailbox.

One way to address this issue is an Outlook add-in API which acts directly on the client. Unfortunately, we don't have such an API. We have a [UserVoice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) for tracking Outlook add-in feature requests. Please add a request there. Feature requests on UserVoice are considered when we go through our planning process.